# Return JSON list with a list key name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm getting the data like this:

```
"[{id: 10, typeID: 4},{id: 100, typeID: 3}]"
```

instead, I want to get the data like this:

```
" name_of_list : [{id: 10, typeID: 4},{id: 100, typeID: 3}]"
```

where `name_of_list` is like a header name or something, I'm new to ASP MVC and I've seen some samples like:

```
return Json(result, "name_of_list", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

I cant find the Json class, its an anonymous variable, I don't know what is that.
please help :)

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
return Json(new { name_of_list= result},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
```

Retrive this in success call using

```
var list=data.name_of_list;
```

Comment: Nitin Varpe, I cant find the Json class.

Comment: @ Nitin Varpe, the problem not in the retrieve, the problem is setting the name, 
return Json(new { name_of_list= result},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
I cant find the Json class, it is giving me an error.

Comment: you have space between word, it isnt following coding conventions. it must be syntax error ',' expected

Comment: @NitinVarpe, return Json(..
can you please tell me what is the namespace of Json ?

Comment: @NitinVarpe, there is no Json class, 
there is JsonResult Class.